# sitecore 9 Experience profile not showing contacts

Tags: experience-profile

i have created a contact with facet in XDB using XConnect programmatically. but created contact is not showing in experience profile and shows no records to display.why this happened?
Also my scenario doesn't require any reporting DB, just want to create a sample data for testing purpose.

Kindly note am using SC9

Comment: I realize the answer on that duplicate is not what your problem is, but you did not provide any additional details to differentiate the problem. The solution here could likely be added as an additional answer to the other question?